# Initialize object containing C-style array as member variable (C++)

Tags: c++, arrays, constructor

Consider the following code:

```
struct Color  // This struct can't be modified
{
    double grey;
    double rgb[3];
};

int main()
{
    double myRGB[3] = {2, 6, 9};

    Color c = {10, myRGB}; // This line doesn't work

    return 0;
}
```

How can I initialize a `Color` object in one line?

In my real case scenario, `Color` struct can't be change (for example, to use `std::array` instead of a C-style array).

Comment: If you *must* use a variable for the initialization, then I suggest you create a constructor for the `Color` structure.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude OP says they can not add constructor, and there is a way to avoid the need for it.

Comment: This code is a very wrong approach to C++ ... it is almost C98. The obvious thing to do is `Color c = { 10, 2, 6, 9}`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Supposing that there is a need to use an intermediate array, here is how one can do it:

```
#include <utility>
#include <cstddef>

struct Color  //this struct can't be modified
{
    double grey;
    double rgb[3];
};

template<size_t N, size_t... IX>
auto make_c_impl(double grey, double (&rgb)[N], std::index_sequence<IX...>) {
    static_assert(sizeof(rgb) == sizeof(Color::rgb), "Arrays sizes must match!");
    return Color{grey, {rgb[IX]...}};
}

template<size_t N>
auto make_c(double grey, double (&rgb)[N]) {
    return make_c_impl(grey, rgb, std::make_index_sequence<N>{});
}
double myRGB[3] = {2, 6, 9};

Color c = make_c(10, myRGB); //this line now works
```

Note, that this code will not actually produce any unnecessary copying with any level of optimization.

Comment: No need to make `make_c` a template: length of `Color::rgb` is known at compile time, so you can just use it (e.g. `sizeof Color::rgb/sizeof*Color::rgb` or, since C++17, `std::size(decltype(Color::rgb){})`).

Comment: @Ruslan, yes, but than we wouldn't be able to present a nice message, and instead a substitute error would be displayed if sizes do not match

Comment: With [`std::apply`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/apply) and [`std::experimental::to_array`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/to_array) the definiton of `make_c` can be shortened to `auto make_c = [](double grey, auto&& rgb) { return std::apply([&](auto&&... args) { return Color{ grey, { args... } }; }, std::experimental::to_array(rgb));` but `Color{ grey, { rgb[0], rgb[1], rgb[2] } }` is still much simpler and easier to understand.

Comment: @cpplearner I already argued that a wider-scoped answer is better than narrow-scoped, and manual indexing of elements is not scalable. `to_array` is a good suggestion.

Comment: Both of you (SergeyA & NathanOliver ) have nice answers. As SergeA mentioned, a generic answers is most of the time expected. That was also my expectation when asking this question. However, when the generic answers become complicated it is nice to mention or illustrate how the problem can be solved in a simpler way as in the case of small array in NathanOliver answer. Thanks to both of you guys

Answer (score 18):

Since `Color` is an aggregate you can use [aggregate initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization) and put the array initializer directly in the braces like

```
Color c = {10, {2, 6, 9}};
```

---

If you have to initialize `c` with an array, since it is small, you can just unroll it like

```
Color c = {10, {myRGB[0], myRGB[1], myRGB[2]}};
```

Comment: I do not think it answers OP's question, looks like they need to initialize from a variable.

Comment: @SergeyA ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯.  The OP hasn't responded for me to know.  I figured they used the array object because they didn't know they didn't need it.  Hopefully they will respond at some point.

Comment: @SergeyA Added an example of how they could "unroll" the array into the initializer.

Comment: Why manual unrolling when it can be done automatically? See my answer.

Comment: @SergeyA Because your answer is half a screen filled with template noise?

Comment: @pipe do you know a better way of doing this without manual repetition? I'd love to see your version!

Comment: @SergeyA No, I'm saying (and the author of this answer) that sometimes manual repetition is perfectly fine, easier to understand and easier to maintain.

Comment: @pipe there is also a question of correctness. My code is guaranteed to work correctly. When you unroll manually, you have a chance of, for example, mixing up the indexes (or even using different arrays!), especially if you have an array of more than 3 elements.

Comment: @SergeyA I agree. OP doesn't have more than 3 elements.

Comment: @pipe I believe a generic question is more important than the specific one - how do you initialize one C-style array from another. Future readers are less likely to benefit from the narrow answer than from the the wider scope one.

Comment: Both of you (NathanOliver  & SergeyA) have nice answers. As SergeA mentioned, a generic answers is most of the time expected. That was also my expectation when asking this question. However, when the generic answers become complicated it is nice to mention or illustrate how the problem can be solved in a simpler way as in the case of small array in NathanOliver answer. Thanks to both of you guys

Answer (score 4):

As complement to others answers, the error is because in [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) arrays are not copyable and trying to initialize an array from an `lvalue` has the semantic of invoking the `copy-constructor`, the same as:

```
double r1[3] = {0., 0., 0.};
double r2[3] {r1} // doesn't compile
```

Your options are:

- do `list-initialization` as @NathanOliver did
- or expand the elements of the array to form a `list-initialization` as in the @SergeyA answer.

Answer (score 1):

Call me a cheat, but...

```
 struct Color final  
{
    double grey;
    double rgb[3];
};
// the cheet
#define make_color( x, a, b ) Color x { a, b[0], b[1], b[2] }

int main()
{
    double myRGB[3]{ 2, 6, 9 };

    make_color( c, 10, myRGB ) ; // single line construction 

    printf("\nColor grey: %f\t rgb:[ %f, %f, %f ]", c.grey, c.rgb[0], c.rgb[1], c.rgb[2] ) ;
}
```

But, since that is pretty atrocious C++, I have taken a liberty of producing something slightly better...

```
struct Color final  
{
    double grey;
    double rgb[3];
};

auto  make_color ( double a, const double(&b)[3] ) { return Color { a, b[0], b[1], b[2] }; }; 
auto  make_color ( double a, double b, double c, double d ) { return Color { a, b, c, d }; }; 
auto print_color ( Color c ) { printf("\nColor grey: %f\t rgb:[ %f, %f, %f ]", c.grey, c.rgb[0], c.rgb[1], c.rgb[2] ) ; }
//
int main()
{
    double myRGB[3]{ 2, 6, 9 };

    auto c = make_color( 10, myRGB ) ; 
    print_color(c);    
    auto z = make_color( 10, 0xFF, 0xA0, 0xB0 ) ; 
    print_color(z);    

}
```

All in a good old SO tradition: do not question the question :)

(the mandatory [Wandbox is here](https://wandbox.org/permlink/vVxZuBmcgQcCo78H))

ps: I like your approach Oliver, although you do not need double braces in those init lists, of course.